# serverside validation with the jQuery validation plugin

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I'm currently starting out with the jQuery validation plugin, and I want to add validation with AJAX using PHP on the backend to validate. To my understanding, that's achieved through something like the following:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      remote: "check-email.php"
    }
  }
});
```

where "check-email.php" would including the proper validation code. However, I'm failing to find an example of what that PHP code might look like. Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: You do realise that users need to just turn JS off and subvert this "validation" and that servers side validation (NOT via ajax)  must be done as well as these checks, your question and the comments thus far might to suggest to any onlooker that this provides server side security, which it does not.

Answer (score 0):

`remote: "check-email.php"` will enable server side validation, not client side. Are you sure that is what you are trying to achieve?

Edit: Here is the documentation for the remote option: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options

Essentially, your php file needs to return true or false, depending on whether the validation was successful or not. Here is how your code should look like:

```
rules: {
    email: {
        required: true,
        remote: "check-email.php"
    }
},
messages: {
    email: "The email entered is incorrect."    
},
submitHandler: function() {
    //alert("Correct email!");
},
success: function(label) {
    label.addClass("valid").text("Valid email!")
}
```

Comment: yeah, I meant serverside. Sorry